# Is the UK Personal Allowance different from the Capital Gains Allowance?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

As per these two resources from the gov.uk website:

- https://www.gov.uk/income-tax-rates
- https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/losses

The standard Personal Allowance for 2019/2020 is £12,500, while the Capital Gains Allowance is £12,000.

This is the first year I will submit a Self Assessment report. Am I correct if I keep these allowances in different baskets? That is, if I go beyond the Personal Allowance with my income, I still have £12,000 left of Capital Gains Allowance, don't I?

Comment: In addition I think you pay either 10% or 20% (or something similar to that) on capital CGT depending on where you are a basic or higher rate income tax payer. See duplicate here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87517/is-the-uk-capital-gains-annual-exempt-amount-separate-from-the-tax-free-personal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, they are separate allowances for different kinds of taxable thing. The personal allowance is the amount of normal income that doesn't get taxed, and the capital gains allowance is the amount of capital gains that don't get taxed.

Of course each of the allowances is only useful if you actually have income or capital gains respectively.

There's some more discussion of how they interact in [this Q+A](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/113002/uk-capital-gains-tax-and-income/113004#113004).